# ¿Cómo obtener solo un correlativo de una tabla detalle al ejecutarse un trigger en sql server?

Tags: sql, trigger

Soy nuevo usando sql server a nivel desarrollo.

Lo que estoy intentando es que en un trigger que esta en la tabla detalle, capturar solo un correlativo de partida, ya que el trigger captura todos los correlativo de la tabla detalle y yo necesito que me capture solo uno.

Por ejemplo:

```
    SELECT CorrelativoMovimiento,CorrelativoActividadFinancieraPrestamos,Monto,Fecha,CorrelativoSucursal,CorrelativoUsuario,CorrelativoPartida FROM d_MovimientoSPrestamos WHERE CorrelativoMovimiento IN (8038182,8038183,8038184)-- 3 cuotas a 3 prestamos y una sola partida contable
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se logran dar cuenta la ultima columna"CorrelativoPartida", es un numero que se repite ya que en esa partida se abonaron a 3 prestamos, pues entonces lo que yo necesito es capturar solo una vez ese correlativoPartida en el trigger para posteriormente hacer un sum() de los intereses cobrados en esas 3 cuotas, (ese desglose se guarda en otra tabla) la cual les muestro a continuación:

```
select DDES.*,TDP.NombreDescuento from d_MovimientosPrestamos dmov inner join d_DescuentosPrestamos DDES on DDES.CorrelativoMovimiento=dmov.CorrelativoMovimient INNER JOIN c_TipoDescuentoPrestamos TDP ON DDES.CorrelativoTipoDescuento=TDP.CorrelativoTipoDescuento where dmov.CorrelativoPartida in (7584185)AND TDP.CorrelativoTipoDescuento in(2,3,4,5,6)-- tipos de intereses cobrados en 3cuotas corresponientes a una misma partida contable
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que yo necesito es sumar los intereses lo que me daria $246.35 y eso irlo a ingresar a otra tabla, peor el problema es que aunque la consulta y la sumatoria si se hace bien, se hace la consulta 3 veces, una vez por cada registro que se guarda es decir por cada correlativoPartida aunque este sea el mismo, en el trigger estaba intentando poner:

```
Declare @CorrelativoPartida bigint
--, @CorrelativoMovimiento bigint
  waitfor delay '00:00:01'
SET @CorrelativoPartida=(select distinct top 1  CorrelativoPartida from inserted)
```

comparto consulta en el triger(funciona bien y luego eso mismo se inserta en la tabla que quiero, solo que 3 veces):

```
select mpa.CorrelativoPartida,mpa.Fecha,derivada1.NombreTipoMovimiento +' '+mpa.ComprobanteSistema+ ' '+rtrim(ccc.Nombre)+' No.'+derivada1.NumeroCuenta as Concepto,0 as Gravado,1 as Exento,dpa.Valor as CostoItem,0 as IvaItem,0 as TotalIva, 0 as TotalGravado,dbo.fn_ExentoTrasladoDTE(dpa.CorrelativoPartida) as TotalExento,0 as NoSujeto,derivada1.CorrelativoAfiliado,6 as CorrelativoTipoTransaccionDTE,derivada1.CorrelativoMovimiento,derivada1.Plazo as Periodo,'Meses 'as Plazo,2 as CodCondicionOperacionMH,'A Credito' as DescCondicionOperacionMH,'07' as CodFormaPagoMH,'Otro' as NomFormaPagoMH  from Contabilidad_..m_Partida mpa inner join Contabilidad_..d_Partida dpa on mpa.CorrelativoPartida=dpa.CorrelativoPartida inner join Contabilidad_..c_CuentasContables ccc on ccc.CorrelativoCuenta=dpa.CorrelativoCuentaContable inner join Contabilidad_..c_TipoMovimientos ctm on ctm.CorrelativoTipoMovimiento=dpa.CorrelativoMovimiento inner join (select top 1 b.CorrelativoAfiliado,b.Plazo,ctMov.NombreTipoMovimiento,a.CorrelativoPartida,a.CorrelativoMovimiento,b.NumeroCuenta from d_MovimientosPrestamos a inner join c_TipoMovimiento ctMov on ctMov.CorrelativoTipoMovimiento=a.CorrelativoTipoMovimiento inner join m_ActividadFinancieraPrestamos b on a.CorrelativoActividadFinancieraPrestamos=b.CorrelativoActividadFinancieraPrestamos where CorrelativoPartida=7584185 and a.CorrelativoTipoMovimiento=8) as derivada1 on derivada1.CorrelativoPartida=mpa.CorrelativoPartida where mpa.CorrelativoPartida=7584185 and ccc.CodigoCuenta in (select CodigoCuenta from c_CuentasContablesInteresesFacturables/* where CodigoCuenta='125030201'*/)
```

Pero no he tenido éxito, ¿alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo?
De antemano gracias...

Comment: Puedes agregar el código del trigger?

Comment: como hago para editar la pregunta?

Comment: @JavierRamirez, en la parte inferior de tu pregunta tienes un enlace que dice [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/608951/edit). ;)

Comment: gracias he añadido la consulta que se hace en el triger, ahi ya puse quemado el correlativoPartida que seria: 7584185

Comment: @LuisCazares, ya he añadido el codigo de la consulta

Comment: Pedí el código del trigger y ese es un SELECT que no incluye las tablas virtuales del trigger (inserted y deleted). Además, es importante darle formato al código.